# Need Help with Zend_Db_Select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I'm currently working with Zend Framework.

just wondering is there a easy way to make my results in Numeric array format rather then associative array?

Eg Here is my zend_db_select statement

```
   $select = $this->select()->from('providerReligionPreference','religionTypeId')
           ->where('providerId = ?',$providerId)
           ->where('quoteTypeId = ?',$quoteTypeId);

   $result = $this->fetchAll($select);

   var_dump($result->toArray());

        return $result->toArray();
```

When I var_dump $result->toArray() I get

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["religionTypeId"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["religionTypeId"]=> string(1) "2" } }
```

But I wanted to be in Numeric array format like

```
$result[0]="1";
$result[1]="2";
```

Can anybody help me out?
Thanks you so much

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your `$result` is a rowset, so you could do something like this:

```
$numericResult = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
     $numericResult []=  $row->religionTypeId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$adapter->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_NUM);
$result = $this->fetchAll($select);
```

or

```
$result = $adapter->fetchAll($select, array(), Zend_Db::FETCH_NUM);
```

assuming `$this` is instance of Zend_Db_Table (No one will extend adapter as model, right?):

```
$result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select, array(), Zend_Db::FETCH_NUM);
```

Comment: Best reply here. Just to add, that I'm not sure, this won't return Rowset too ;) But if it does, you can use `$this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);` and `$this->getAdapter()->setFetchMode()` that works 100% :)

Comment: You are correct. Will look into rowset to see if it can work with numeric keys

Comment: No, Table can't work with other modes as it explicitly specified associative fetch mode: `$data = $stmt->fetchAll(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$adapter->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_NUM);
$select = $adapter->select();
...
```

or even both

```
$adapter->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

The return of `fetchAll`is a rowset, like explain in : http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.db.table.rowset.html

The rowset implement "SeekableIterator" and "Countable" : http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Db/Table/Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract.html

Use:

```
$myAssocArray = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $myAssocArray[] = $row->religionTypeId;
}
```